# flow through the island's economy

Tags: word-usage

In the book "How an Economy Grows and Why It Crashes" by Peter D. Schiff, chapter 7, page 82, paragraph 1, there is the sentence:

> The splashing success of the Water Works project flowed through the island's economy.

"flow through" confused me.

I know the meaning --cash flow--in the below sentence.

> When I get a little cash flow at the end of the week, I’ll treat you to a hamburger.

I know the meaning --flow through--in the below sentence.

> The River Thames flows through London.

How to parse "flow through" in the sentence?

> The splashing success of the Water Works project flowed through the island's economy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the author is using "splash" and "flow" to allude to the **water** works project, perhaps a bit too cleverly. Here "flowed thoruh" simply means "traveled through" or "affected many parts of", it is a metaphor.

The sentence could be rewritten more simply as:

> The great success of the Water Works project affected many parts of the island's economy.

"flowed through" implies affected one part, then another, then another, as a flow of water moves through something.  But this is a nuance which is probably not essential to the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Here through means **From one end or side of sth/sb to the other**.

The sentence is a bit figurative. It means-

> The water works project was so successful that it affected the economy completely esp in a positive way.